# CSS text overflow ellipsis with multiple elements

Tags: html, css

Here is what I want to do:

1. Keep some text and a button at the same line and align center
2. When reduce the screen size, always keep the button showing up while **text-overflow: ellipsis** taking effect

What I did so far can't keep the button showing up. Ellipsis only starts working when the window edge reaches the text.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>
    foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar 
  </span>
  <button type="button">Download</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #b3ffcb;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wl880504/y7404myo)

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I made a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/y7404myo/1/, hope it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` on wrapper and apply `text-overflow: ellipsis` on `span` [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/y7404myo/3/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #b3ffcb;
}
span {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar </span>
  <button type="button">Download</button>
</div>
```

Comment: When I continually reduce the screen, the button size somehow got reduced gradually too. What is this happening?

Comment: @Li' I can't see that in my demo, can you create `fiddle` and show what you mean by that?

Comment: Nvm, I added button min-width to fix button size issue. Flexbox is what I need to solve my problem. Thx!